# .Net Core Late Bind Dynamic Implementation Factory

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-core, owin

I'm trying to figure out the best way to change existing implementation factories to dynamically register events from my signalr hubs to my generic service.

Originally I was going to have the hub injected into the service but I don't want to couple them or have client have to implement their own hubs etc, so I decided to create an event for subscription

But I don't want the client to have to register their own factory I would like to take all of the existing ones and generically register them based off of a configuration option:

I have a generic crud service a simplified version looks like so

```
public interface IAsyncCRUDService<TDTO>
{
    Task<TDTO> Get(object[] id);
    Task<TDTO[]> GetList(IFilterResolver queryOptions);
    Task<TDTO> Create(TDTO skillDTO);
    Task<TDTO> Update(object[] id, TDTO skillDTO);
    Task<bool> Delete(object[] id);

    event EventHandler<TDTO> OnCreate;
    event EventHandler<TDTO> OnUpdate;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to have a configuration to use automatically register my hubs events to my service.

```
public interface ICRUDServiceHubBase<in T>
{
    Task Create(T entityDTO);
    Task Update(T entityDTO);
    Task Delete(object[] id);
}
```

In my startup I want to automatically register the events for the services. I wanted this to be easy and configurable

```
    //TODO: Move to extensions
    protected List<ServiceDescriptor> GetGenericServicesFromGenericTypeDefinition(IServiceCollection services, Type baseGenericTypeDefinition)
    {
        if(false == baseGenericTypeDefinition.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Invalid Argument {nameof(baseGenericTypeDefinition)}");
        }

       return services.Where(s => s.ImplementationType.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType)
            .Where(s => s.ImplementationType.GetTypeInfo().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == baseGenericTypeDefinition).ToList()

    }

    public EventHandler<TDTO> RegisterHubsCreate<TDTO>(IAsyncCRUDService<TDTO> service, ICRUDServiceHubBase<TDTO> hubService)
    {
        EventHandler<TDTO> handlerRef = (object obj, TDTO args) => { hubService.Create(args); };
        service.OnCreate += handlerRef;
        return handlerRef;
    }

    public void RegisterHubsEvents(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var crudServiceDescriptors = this.GetGenericServicesFromGenericTypeDefinition(services, typeof(IAsyncCRUDService<>));

        foreach (var serviceDescriptor in crudServiceDescriptors)
        {
            var originalFunc = serviceDescriptor.ImplementationFactory;

            Func<IServiceProvider, object> HubsRegistered = (IServiceProvider provider) => {
                var serviceObj = originalFunc(provider);
                //TODO: since this is an instance you probably need to grab the interface type first
                //or you'll risk grrabbing the wrong parameter
                var dtoType = serviceObj.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First();
                var hubType = typeof(ICRUDServiceHubBase<>).MakeGenericType(dtoType);

                //Is this risky if the hub is transient will my object be disposed before the event fires?
                var hub = provider.GetService(hubType);

                var registerHubsDynamically = this.GetType().GetMethod("RegisterHubsCreate").MakeGenericMethod(dtoType);
                registerHubsDynamically.Invoke(this, new object[] { serviceObj, hub });

                return serviceObj;
            };

            serviceDescriptor.ImplementationFactory = HubsRegistered;

        }
    }
```

How can I dynamically send an implementation factory, or maybe some how have an event that registers when even the implementation factory is called?

Comment: In case anyone’s wonder I’ve modified my the service factory so the hubs are registered in the service creation.  Alternatively, if you want to really register then dynamically you can use a modified decorator pattern, to grab out the func which returns your service and create a new func which uses the original to create it and then register the events before returning